# How to open a QuickContact by Contact ID

Tags: android-layout, android-contacts, android-dialog

i want to know how open QuickContact by "contactID" OR "PhoneNumber" then start the activity

> looks something like this

[image]

this tutorial seems good : [how-to-use-quickcontactbadge-in-android](https://www.wonderbits.net/en/posts/8-how-to-use-quickcontactbadge-in-android)

> For example :
> i have function to open contact by ID, i want way similar to this
> function but for QuickContactBadge

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(mPerson.getContactID()));
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code example extracted from Android 4.4.4

```
final Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToNext() && !cursor.isNull(0)) {
    Intent intent = ContactsContract.QuickContact.composeQuickContactsIntent(
            mContext, v, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
            ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, null);
    mContext.startActivityAsUser(intent, new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT));
```

open quick contact by contact ID

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contact_id));
Intent intent = ContactsContract.QuickContact.composeQuickContactsIntent(
    mContext, v, uri,
    ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, null);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```